# getting the area of two intersecting rectangles

Tags: java

i'm sincerely confusing myself here... which one actually returns the area of intersection between two rectangles? pleas explain (math frustrates me). any help would be appreciated.

**APPROACH ONE:**

```
double newX = Math.max(this.x, rect2.x);
double newY = Math.max(this.y, rect2.y);
return new Rect(newX, newY, Math.min(this.x + this.width, rect2.x + rect2.width) - newX, Math.min(this.y
        + this.height, rect2.y + rect2.height)
        - newY);
```

**APPROACH TWO:**

```
double areaOfIntersection = Math.max(0, Math.max(rect1x2, rect2x2) - Math.min(rect1x1, rect2x1))
                        * Math.max(0, Math.max(rect1y2, rect2y2) - Math.min(rect1y1, rect2y1));
```

Comment: I think this question suits well here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this a math question or a programming question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. The way you posted the code is confusing because it seems `this` refers to one rect and `rect2` refers to a second rect. Why not make an `Rect#area()` method instead of computing the area of intersection separately?

```
class Rect {

    double x, y, width, height;

    ... members and stuff

    Rect intersection(Rect rect2) {
        double newX = Math.max(this.x, rect2.x);
        double newY = Math.max(this.y, rect2.y);

        double newWidth = Math.min(this.x + this.width, rect2.x + rect2.width) - newX;
        double newHeight = Math.min(this.y + this.height, rect2.y + rect2.height) - newY;

        if (newWidth <= 0d || newHeight <= 0d) return null;

        return new Rect(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    double area() {
        return this.width * this.height;
    }

}
```

Then you would just do

```
Rect intersection = rect1.intersection(rect2);    
double areaOfIntersection = intersection == null ? 0 : intersection.area();
```

Comment: Does this handle the case when the rectangles don't intersect at all?

Comment: @AndrewMao actually.... i'm not sure this works... the code i posted above were two totally distinct approaches..

Comment: Fixed for the case where they don't intersect at all.

Comment: this does not work, gives me negative area.

Answer (score 1):

heres what i would do:

break down the rectangles into 4 points each - and order them:

you only need to compare the correcpoinding points of each rectangle.
each has:
- upper left
- upper right
- lower left
- lower right

to calcuate the x,y value of the upper left point of the rectangle created by the intersection:

first calculate the x coordinate of the upper left corner by getting the rightmost point (highest x value) since we are looking for the left corner

```
if rect_1_upper_left_x > rect_2_upper_left_x then
    intersect_upper_left_x = rect_1_upper_left_x
else
    intersect_upper_left_x = rect_2_upper_left_x
endif
```

or more simply

```
intersect_upper_left_x = max( rect_1_upper_left_x , rect_2_upper_left_x )
```

to get the y coordinate of the upper left corner, choose the lowest y value (since we are looking for the top corner)

```
intersect_upper_left_y = min( rect_1_upper_left_y , rect_2_upper_left_y )
```

note that you only need to do this for 2 opposite corners;

ex: upper left and lower right

edit: although, if your upper left is lower than your lower right, they do not instersect.
same as if your upper left is more to the right than your lower right...

Comment: also, this only works if the recangles are not at an angle, but that seems to be implied by code shown in the the question